# Complement of an almost open set is almost open

Tags: measure-theory

I have been studying Measure Theory, and I am trying to solve a problem about σ-algebras.

> A subset of a topological space is said to be *almost open* or to *have the Property of Baire* if it is the symmetric difference of an open set and a meager set.

The goal is to prove Ba(X) = {A ⊆ X : A is almost open}, where X is a topological space, is a σ-algebra. More specifically, I cannot see why the complement of an almost open set is almost open. My attempts involved trying to expand:

> $$
> \begin{align}
> X\setminus(A\,\Delta\,B) & = X\setminus((A\setminus B)\, \cup \,(B\setminus A)) \\
> & = X\setminus(A\setminus B)\, \cap \,X\setminus(B\setminus A) \\
> & = X\setminus(A \cap X\setminus B)\, \cap \,X\setminus(B \cap X\setminus A) \\
> & = ((X\setminus A) \cup B)\, \cap \,((X \setminus B) \cup A) \\
> & = (A \cap B)\, \cup \,((X \setminus A) \cap (X \setminus B)) \\
> & = (A \cap B)\, \cup \,(X \setminus (A \cup B)) \\
> \end{align}
> $$

And $(X \setminus A)\,\Delta\, (X \setminus B) = A\,\Delta\,B$. But the complement of a meager set is not meager. How can I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Update

It is probably easier to see this using some elementary facts about symmetric difference, namely, that symmetric difference is associative, and the symmetric difference of a disjoint union is the same as the actual union, so that $U^c= \bar{U}^c\Delta \partial U$ for an open set $U$.

We then have, for an almost open set $A=U\Delta M$,
\begin{align*}
A^c &= (U\Delta M)^c =X\Delta(U\Delta M)= (X\Delta U)\Delta M \\ &= U^c\Delta M = (\bar{U}^c\Delta \partial U) \Delta M
= \bar{U}^c\Delta (\partial U \Delta M)
\end{align*}
Since $\partial U$ and $M$ are meager, so is the symmetric difference, as it is contained in the union, and $\bar{U}^c$ is open, so $A^c$ is almost open.

---

#### Original Answer

If $U$ is open and $M$ is meager, notice first that $M\backslash U$ is meager, and therefore every almost open set has the form
$$(U\backslash M_1)\cup M_2\tag{1}$$
for $U$ open and $M_1$, $M_2$ meager.

Conversely, any set of the form (1) has WLOG $M_1\subseteq U$ and $M_2\cap U=\emptyset$  (otherwise replace $M_1$ with $M_1\cap U$ and $M_2$ with $M_2\cap (U\backslash M_1)^c$), so it can be rewritten as $U\Delta (M_1\backslash M_2)$, and is hence almost open.

Also, for every open set $U$, we have $U^c=\partial U \cup \bar{U}^c$, with $\partial U$ nowhere dense, hence meager.

Therefore, taking the complement of a general almost open set $A$ gives us

\begin{align*}
A^c & = ((U\backslash M_1)\cup M_2)^c = ((U\cap M_1^c)\cup M_2)^c
= (U\cap M_1^c)^c\cap M_2^c\\ &= (U^c\cup M_1)\cap M_2^c
= (\partial U \cup \bar{U}^c\cup M_1)\cap M_2^c\\ &=(\bar{U}^c\backslash M_2) \cup (\partial U \cup M_1)\backslash M_2.
\end{align*}
Since $\bar{U}^c$ is open, and $(\partial U \cup M_1)\backslash M_2$, as a subset of a meager set, is meager, we have written $A^c$ in the form (1), and so $A^c$ is almost open.